# Why proxy server cannot receive response from server

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to design a simple proxy server for the client to access the website. I use the following code to get the message from the client.

```
tcpSerSock.bind(('', 9999))
tcpSerSock.listen(1)
tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
print("Received a connection from:", addr)# Fill in start.
message = tcpCliSock.recv(1024).decode(encoding="utf-8")
```

Then I tried to forward the message from the proxy to the server, and then get the file from the server so that I can send it from the proxy server to the client.

```
proxySock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
proxySock.connect(('baidu.com', 80))
proxySock.sendall(message.encode(encoding="utf-8"))
respondMsg = proxySock.recv(1024).decode(encoding="utf-8")
```

However, the proxy cannot receive message from server, and it seems to because 'the server is reset'. I did some research and found it may be related to the message sent to it. The message is shown below, I don't know what is wrong with it since it is attained from the client. Could someone help me figure out what is wrong?

```
GET /www.baidu.com HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9999
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> GET /www.baidu.com HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9999
> ```

This is not the message expected by the server. The server expects a message like this

```
  GET / HTTP/1.1
  Host: www.baidu.com
```

Thus, you cannot simply forward the message you've received to the server but must change it. Note though that from my test the server will not reset the connection but will instead reply with

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: bfe
...
```

Apart from that:

```
message = tcpCliSock.recv(1024).decode(encoding="utf-8")
...
proxySock.sendall(message.encode(encoding="utf-8"))
respondMsg = proxySock.recv(1024).decode(encoding="utf-8")
```

The data transferred should not be treated as UTF-8 but as binary. In fact, historically the HTTP header as allowed ISO-8859-1 encoding although now it is defined as ASCII only. And the payload can just be anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reminding me of that. However, I use 'replace' to change the message and transfer again, but it still fails. I used try and except at first, and then after deleting them, I found it says "respondMsg = proxySock.recv(1024).decode(encoding="utf-8")
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer". Still very confusing. Also, in terms of data transferred, if I do not use encode, decode, it will give error as well.

Comment: Edited: I use Wireshark to check the message of GET sent to server and found it used POST instead. Not sure whether it is the reason. Therefore I used "http://localhost:8888/www.example.org" instead, which used GET for sure, found it can run.